# Check if jupyter notebooks run without errors from cli

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-console

I am trying to check if .ipynb files can be executed through **cmd line**, I have looked at runipy and papermill. I am more specifically looking for exit code 0, but none of the packages mentioned above check if the code fails anywhere. Papermill still returns exit code 0 even after a python exception. Are there any other packages that do this?

I am looking at something like

`some_pkg execute-notebook my_notebook.ipynb`

which could give me an exit code based on if the entire code is run successfully or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following cli instruction from the cmd line:
`jupyter nbconvert --execute your_notebook.ipynb`

For that, you will need to install the package `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` with `pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

This way should give you an error message if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [nbmake](https://github.com/treebeardtech/nbmake) and pytest.

```bash
pip install pytest nbmake

pytest --nbmake **/*ipynb
```